# Confusions regarding meaning of "kernel" in signal processing and image processing?

Tags: image-processing, filters, terminology, kernel

While studying filters in DSP and DIP, the term "kernel" is often encountered
**What is the meaning of "kernel" in context of filters**??Please kindly explain in simple words with an example

I have also attached a snapshot from gonzalez

**What is meant by "neighborhood of operation" here?**

and in last line,author says that mask,template & window terms are synonyms for kernel.

**Is it true even in case of FIR windows such as Hanning window,Blackman window etc? Those windows are also kernels?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of "kernel" in context of filters?

A "kernel" is the thing you convolve by.  So for a FIR filter that's defined by the taps $k = \begin{bmatrix}a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$, $k$ is the kernel.

For a 2D filtering problem, the kernel would, in general, be 2D (and you tend to see the term much more often in image processing, but I've also seen it in really highfalutin' stochastic signal processing literature).

> What is meant by "neighborhood of operation" here?

For an output pixel at position $\begin{bmatrix}x, y\end{bmatrix}$, all of the pixels in the input image that affect the output.  In general, if you have an $n \times m$ kernel, the neighborhood of operation is $n \times m$.

> Is it true even in case of FIR windows such as Hanning window,Blackman window etc? Those windows are also kernels?

Different disciplines, different terminologies.  No, because those don't define filter kernels -- the "windowing" operation is different from the "windowing" in 2D image processing.

Comment: "Different disciplines, different terminologies. No, because those don't define filter kernels -- the "windowing" operation is different from the "windowing" in 2D image processing"   What do you mean here? The term "window" has different meaning in DSP and DIP??

Comment: Yes.  Typically, in DSP when you window a signal you're multiplying it point-by-point with a function that tapers off to zero amplitude at the ends, so that when you take an FFT the result better approximates the spectrum of the (presumably) infinitely long signal that you sampled.